# PHP - mysql_numrows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm new here (in PHP too :D) and I'm trying to install a lottery script but get this error:

> Warning: mysql_numrows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/u289308161/public_html/lottery/get_lottery.php on line 7 Table 'u289308161_lot.lottery' doesn't exist

u289308161_lot is the database name and the user that uses it.

The get_lottery.php file is:

```
    <?php
require 'connect.php';

$query="SELECT * FROM lottery ORDER BY lottery_id DESC LIMIT 10";
$result=mysql_query($query);

$num=mysql_numrows($result);

?>
```

Please help!

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11674313/250259) for how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Well, you read the whole error… so does `lottery` exist or not? (It doesn’t, but where *does* it exist?)

Answer (score 1):

This means that num_rows() can't give a result back because the query is failing.
You always need to know if a query is failing:

```
<?php
require 'connect.php';

$query  = "SELECT * FROM lottery ORDER BY lottery_id DESC LIMIT 10";
$result =mysql_query($query);

if($result == false)
{
    echo 'The query failed.';
    exit();
}

$num = mysql_num_rows($result);

?>
```

Comment: Yes, now i get The query failed. What to do next?

Comment: You now need to know why the query is failing, after I saw the error you gaved us I can see that you don't have the SQL code for the lottery script.

Comment: Replace  `echo 'the query failed.';` with `echo mysql_error();` and tell us what error do you get.

Comment: @Joke_Sense10 He already gave us the error he was getting, you're right but I needed to know if the query worked or not.

Comment: Than you very much! I have forgotten to import the sql files. Thanks again!

Comment: But says as No database selected, But Successfully Selected database